# Web.Config Allow access to login.aspx only

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, authorization

I have a folder, ~/Account that has numerous pages in it. I want all the pages protected from anonymous access except the Login.aspx page (for obvious reasons).  I cannot seem to come up with the correct web.config to do this.   Here is the one I have at present:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>    
</configuration>
```

Can anyone give me a hand at the correct settings?  Thanks!

Comment: It looks ok. What issues are you having?

Comment: Well I go to the ~/account/login.aspx page and I get page not found.

Comment: But that would indicate that the page does not exist, not that it is not accessible (when found)

Comment: The actual message is "The resource cannot be found.".   If I take out the web.config and refresh, no problem.  if I take out the first "deny users "?"" its fine too.